# How to find Window's API names with @number?

Tags: windows, nasm

I'm trying to program in assembly for fun. And to access the console i.e. print and take user input.

I found this from Microsoft which almost has everything I need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole, but in order to add the function to my assemble it needs an @ followed by a number. How do I find the number to use after the '@'?

```
global _start

extern _GetStdHandle@4
extern _WriteConsoleA@20
;-----extern _ReadConsole@SOME_NUMBER_HERE
extern _ExitProcess@4

%define STDOUT dword -11

;init items
section .data
    str: db 'hello, world', 0x0D, 0x0A
    strLen: equ $-str
    
;0-init items
section .bss
    numCharsWritten: resd 1

;code
section .text
_start:
    
    mov ebx, strLen
    mov ecx, str
    call .write
    
    push dword 0
    call _ExitProcess@4
    
;ebx - length, ecx - string
.write:
    push STDOUT
    call _GetStdHandle@4
    
    push dword 0
    push numCharsWritten
    ;push dword strLen
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push eax
    call _WriteConsoleA@20
    
    ret
```

compiling:
`nasm -f win32 $(FILE_NAME) -o $(NAME_PART).o`
`ld -e _start $(NAME_PART).o -l kernel32 -o $(NAME_PART).exe`

Comment: `@` indicates number of 4 byte arguments, for `ReadConsole` it is 4*5=20, but you don't need it - just import it like `extern ReadConsole 
import ReadConsole kernel32.dll`

Comment: Thank you so much!